# How to get youtube like timed-bookmark effect on local mp4 files?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, bookmarks, youtube

Youtube or most other video sharing site take a URL parameter that specifies the time in mm:ss format from start of video, from where playback should start if the link is clicked ? Preferably something that is scriptable or something that allows me to edit the bookmark and timeline in a text file or something.

How could I achieve the same ? So far, I've managed to use VLCplayer's bookmark facility within the playlist facility, but it is quite cumbersome as I need to actually navigate the timeline of the entire video, and be lucky to hit pause and CTRL-B just at the right moment, to create a new bookmark, rename it etc. Many a time I either end up adding bookmark a bit too early or too late, and the VLCplayer bookmark facility doesn't allow me to manually edit the time (only bookmark description). Is there a personal webserver plugin, that'd allow me to dishout local mepg4 files and access them with a "&t=00:37:06" type of URL suffix clicking the URL would actually let me skip the video right up to that time, in my browser ?

Answer (score 3):

VLC offers the command-line option `--start-time` to jump to a specific time when opeing a video:

```
 vlc --start-time=83.4 --stop-time=300 BigBuckBunny.ogv
```

Therefore you could create cmd line file(s) in the file system as workaround for a bookmark system.

[source](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Jump_to_a_certain_time/)

Comment: Good command line option, but I believe should be spelled like 'opening' or 'open'.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely edit bookmark time as you want in KMPlayer.

Start playing a video with KMPlayer -> right-click on the playing window and choose Bookmarks/Chapter - > choose Add to bookmarks.

Then choose Bookmarks/Chapter - > Edit bookmarks, edit the time and optionally, name the chapter.